# CQ5 Reverse replication: polling is not happening

Tags: aem

I have created a form using the OOTB form components. While submission it is hitting the service that I've written in the `post.POST.html`. It creates the nodes with primary type of `cq:Page`  and `jcr:content` with primary type of `cq:PageContent` under the path `/content/usergenerated/content`. I also have added `cq:distribute` property to `"true"`. I have done all configurations for both the Author and Publish modes. The nodes are created under the above mentioned path. The problem that I'm getting is polling is not happening in my case. I'm unable to see the changes in Author mode while the nodes are creating in the Publish mode.

My console is printing this in Author mode:

```
19.05.2016 12:13:43.767 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse Sending GET request to http://localhost:4503/bin/receive?sling:authRequestLogin=1
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse sent. Response: 200 OK
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse ------------------------------------------------
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse Sending message to localhost:4503
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse >> GET /bin/receive?sling:authRequestLogin=1 HTTP/1.0
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse >> Action: Internal Poll
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse >> Path: 
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse >> Handle: 
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse --
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse << Date: Thu, 19 May 2016 06:43:43 GMT
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse << X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse << Content-Type: application/octet-stream
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse << Content-Length: 32
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse << Server: Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse << X-Powered-By: Jetty(9.2.9.v20150224)
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse Message sent.
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse ------------------------------------------------
19.05.2016 12:13:43.786 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse Reverse replication successful.
19.05.2016 12:13:43.787 *INFO* [pool-6-thread-4] com.day.cq.replication.Agent.publish_reverse Fetched 0 contents from http://localhost:4503/bin/receive?sling:authRequestLogin=1 since null
```